# Google Query function not filtering the right way (Order by desc)

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Good day,

I'm facing an issue with the Google Query function. Indeed I'm trying to us the below :

```
=query(RESEARCH!A4:O,"Select A, D, E, K, N, O, C, H where E is not null and not E contains 'SPOT' order by E Desc",0)
```

But for some reasons it's not ordering E the right way. Strange thing is that if I chose B it works perfectly fine. I double checked that my columns where in number format.

Does anyone know from where it could come from please ?

Thank you in advance for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: There should be no problems with your formula, it all boils down to the data you are trying to sort/order. Can you at least show the data you want to sort in your post?

Comment: Good day, 

thank you very much for your quick answer. Unfortunately I can't share the actual spreadsheet as there is some confidential information in it but I found the source of the error. The data of the column that I wanted to sort (column E) where coming with the below formula :

=iferror(vlookup(B4,'Name of the tab'!$A:$G,2,FALSE),"SPOT")

The fact that I put non numerical data if there was an error made the query formula not working well. I took off the iferror formula of my data and now the Query function is working perfectly fine.

Thank you for your help. Have a nice day !